# Set opacity of QToolTip so no bleedthrough of underlying text

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I set the background color of QToolTip (attached to a label) using setStyleSheet, yet the color is light and the underlying text shows/bleeds through the tooltip.  I looked on this site and found I should be able to set the opacity to 1 to control this issue.  I tried it, but the tooltip now shows for less than a second and then disappears. Obviously, I misinterpreted the other posts and/or cannot convert their C examples into the style I use.  Code with the opacity in it:

```
child.setStyleSheet(child.styleSheet() + 'QToolTip {'
                                                     ' background-color: #E6F3FF; font-size: 13px;'
                                                     ' color: black; font-weight: Bold; border: 2px solid #1e90ff;'
                                                     ' border-radius: 6px; padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px; opacity: 1; }')
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a value that's too low for the [opacity property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#opacity-prop):

> The opacity for a widget. Possible values are from 0 (transparent) to 255 (opaque).

Set the opacity to 255 and it should work as expected.